# Greatest Common Divisor for Multiple Numbers

Tags: javascript

I came up with this code to solve for the greatest common divisor for multiple numbers, however, because of the use of recursion, if a number is too large (say 4 digits and over) then the max call stack size is exceeded. Can I improve the code to fix this?

```js
let arr = [10, 40, 395]
let maxNum = Math.max(...arr) 
      
function getGCD(){       
    arr.forEach(function (arrNum){
        if (maxNum === 0){
            return 1;
        }

 if (arrNum % maxNum === 0) { 
   return maxNum;
 }

        maxNum--; 
        getGCD();     
    });

    return maxNum;
}

console.log (getGCD())
```

Comment: There's no reason to use recursion here; you're basically just iterating from the largest number down until you find a result. Use a `for` loop instead.

Comment: Additionally, the GCD cannot be larger than the smallest number in the set, so you can replace `Math.max` with `Math.min` instead to shave off a lot of iterations.

Comment: See the [Euclidean Algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_algorithm) for a better way to calculate GCD

Comment: Using recursion in this case is a *really* bad idea. For example, what happens when you have an array of length 10,000,000?  Recursion is better suited to problems that are difficult to solve with an iterative approach. Not to mention the iterative approach will be faster.